# Рабочий код не работает на домашнем сервере

Tags: php

На хостинге этот код работает как часы, на домашнем в браузере ошибка 500 в приложении которое отправляет запрос ошибка 501

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$dbuser = "home_user";
$dbpass = "AZ*******l9";
$db = "data";
$charset = 'utf8';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = [
           PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
           PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
           PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
       ];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass, $opt);

$id = $_GET["id"];
$data = $_GET["data"];
$sql = "INSERT INTO `data_table` (`id`, `data`) VALUES ('".$id."', '".$data."');";
$send = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$send->execute();
echo("ok");
?>
```

Однако если удалить $opt то сервер начинает возвращать "ok" но ничего в базу не заносит... магия...

Server: ubuntu server 16.--; apache2 2.4.18; php 7.0.8; mysql 5.7

Вставляю код

```
print($send->errorInfo());
```

или

```
try{...} catch (PDOException $e)
{
    print($e);
}
```

Результат один "Страница 192.168.0.101 не работает". никаких признаков жизни...

Comment: ну дак включите отображение ошибок, проверьте ошибки возвращаемые `execute()`. 500 ошибка из за выбрасывания исключения PDO вероятно происходит, как у вас в `$opt` и настроено. а когда `opt` убираете, то исключения не выбрасываются и код как бы работает, но что логично, работает некорректно. Можете проверить, заккоментировав только строку с `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`, а не `$opt` целиком

Comment: @teran не получается...

Comment: @teran коменчу указанную вами строку но ничего не происходит, все так же не работает

Comment: @ВладимирАлександров А локально у вас какая версия php установлена?

Comment: FYI: 1) У вас в коде `SQLInjection`. 2) `prepared statments`Используются по другому! Правильно: `$sql = "INSERT INTO `data_table` (`id`, `data`) VALUES (?,  ?)";
$send = $pdo->prepare($sql); $send->execute([$id, $data]);`. Что так же защищает от `SQLInjection` http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: А по делу, включайте сообшения об ошибках и смотрите логи php и сервера. Из вариантов 1) Не все расширения PHP установленны. 2) Неправильно установленна/сконфигурированна база данных.

Answer (score 0):

Владимир, включите отображение ошибок `php`. Для этого после открывающего `<?php` добавьте следующие строки:

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
```

Думаю, это поможет Вам отследить, что именно не хочет работать в скрипте